# Nested Route in React Router Dom v6

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component called `ParentComponent`, which has two parts. A component that is fixed and is shown on the right side of the screen and on the left side of the screen is a component that is dynamic and changes when the route screen changes. The problem I'm having is that the left component is displayed below the right component, not next to it.

```
import React from 'react'
import Component1 from './Component1'
import Component2 from './Component2'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

function AllComponents() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      </div>

      <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
        {/* //Fixed Component On Right Side of Screen */}
        <Component1 />
      </div>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

export default AllComponents
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AllComponents from "./Components/AllComponents";
import Component2 from "./Components/Component2";
import Component3 from "./Components/Component3";
import Component4 from "./Components/Component4";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/parent" element={<AllComponents />}>
            <Route path='component2' element={<Component2 />} />
            <Route path='component3' element={<Component3 />} />
            <Route path='component4' element={<Component4 />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Component1() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link to='/parent/component2'>
          <h1>Go To Component2</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/parent/component3'>
          <h1>Go To Component3</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/parent/component4'>
          <h1>Go To Component3</h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Component1
```

Comment: In `AllComponents` I see two stacked `div` elements and an `Outlet`, e.g. 3 vertically oriented UI elements. [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-route-in-react-router-dom-v6-2847qj). Can you [edit] to clarify in better detail how exactly you want the UI layout to work? What do you want next to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the culprit is how you've got flexbox set up. Your Component1 and Outlet are each wrapped in their own flex containers, making them stack vertically.

To have them side by side, just do the following:

1. Wrap both Outlet and Component1 in one parent div with display: flex.
2. Inside this parent, wrap Outlet in a div with flex: 1 style, making it take all the available space.
3. For Component1, wrap it in a div with flexShrink: 0 to ensure it doesn't shrink and maintains its width.

Here's a revised version of your AllComponents:

```js
function AllComponents() {
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <h1> Parent Component </h1>
            </div>

            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <div style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Outlet />
                </div>
                <div style={{flexShrink: 0}}>
                    <Component1 />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Give it a shot and see if that helps! And, of course, make sure the contents of your other components (like Component2, Component3, and Component4) aren't spilling over or anything.

Hope that solves your issue!